# how to pass the values from 1st screen to 4th screen using react native?

Tags: react-native

i could able to pass the values from 1st screen to 2nd screen using react navigation but i want to pass the Text Input value from first screen to fourth screen.it would be grateful if anyone helps me out

Comment: just pass the value in props

Answer (score 1):

Use redux  to store the input values, then that values will be available everywhere
in the application,

[For more details refer](https://redux.js.org/introduction/getting-started)

Answer (score 0):

Please read the doc of react navigation, passing parameters to routes

[here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/params.html)

```
class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
        <Text>Home Screen</Text>
        <Button
          title="Go to Details"
          onPress={() => {
            /* 1. Navigate to the Details route with params */
            this.props.navigation.navigate('Details', {
              itemId: 86,
              otherParam: 'anything you want here',
            });
          }}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

class DetailsScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    /* 2. Get the param, provide a fallback value if not available */
    const { navigation } = this.props;
    const itemId = navigation.getParam('itemId', 'NO-ID');
    const otherParam = navigation.getParam('otherParam', 'some default value');

    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
        <Text>Details Screen</Text>
        <Text>itemId: {JSON.stringify(itemId)}</Text>
        <Text>otherParam: {JSON.stringify(otherParam)}</Text>
        <Button
          title="Go to Details... again"
          onPress={() =>
            this.props.navigation.push('Details', {
              itemId: Math.floor(Math.random() * 100),
            })}
        />
        <Button
          title="Go to Home"
          onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Home')}
        />
        <Button
          title="Go back"
          onPress={() => this.props.navigation.goBack()}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

## Basic concept, if u want pass value from A to B

1. At Page A , pass `itemId` and `otherParam` 
   `this.props.navigation.navigate('Details', {
     itemId: 86,
      otherParam: 'anything you want here',
   });`
2. At Page B, Create a variable to get the value bu using `navigation.getParam`

`const itemId = navigation.getParam('itemId', 'NO-ID');
 const otherParam = navigation.getParam('otherParam', 'some default value');`

Comment: exactly this is what i tried. as per my requirement i also want same item id in my 4th 5th screen

Comment: @MSM great that help. please mark my answer :) thanks

Comment: @MSM I am sure that u will have multiple link at Page A right? think simple..

`this.props.navigation.navigate('Page B', { itemID : 1 })`
`this.props.navigation.navigate('Page D', { itemID : 1 })`

Comment: i am moving from A-B,B-C,C-D,D-E.In A i am entering 234, it should come in B,E,F

Comment: I think redux is your best way to solve.. but if u really want to use react navigation to pass value.. you can just continue pass the value from A to E. 

Example: `At Page B`

`const valueFromA = navigation.getParam('itemID');
this.props.navigation.navigate('Page C', valueFromA)`

`At Page C`
`const valueFromB = navigation.getParam('valueFromA');
this.props.navigation.navigate('Page D', valueFromB)`

Answer (score 0):

`AsyncStorage` is available.

You can save the values and pass them to all the screens that You want.

> Importing the `AsyncStorage` library:

```js
import {AsyncStorage} from 'react-native';
```

> Persisting data:

```js
_storeData = async () => {
  try {
    await AsyncStorage.setItem('@MySuperStore:key', 'I like to save it.');
  } catch (error) {
    // Error saving data
  }
};
```

> Fetching data:

```js
_retrieveData = async () => {
  try {
    const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('TASKS');
    if (value !== null) {
      // We have data!!
      console.log(value);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    // Error retrieving data
  }
};
```

> Example.js

```js
//saveScreen
import {AsyncStorage} from 'react-native';
...
_storeData = async () => {
  try {
    await AsyncStorage.setItem('@MySuperStore:key', 'I like to save it.');
  } catch (error) {
    // Error saving data
  }
};
...

//your storage data use Screen
import {AsyncStorage} from 'react-native';
...
componentDidMount(){
 try {
    const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('TASKS');
    if (value !== null) {
      // We have data!!
      console.log(value);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    // Error retrieving data
  }
}
```